# Finding the next 9am/pm from now

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have some code that needs to return a `datetime` of the next 9am or 9pm, UTC. I've figured out some code to do this, but it feels unnecessarily complex to me. Is there a way to simplify this?

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

class NineOClockTimes:
    @staticmethod
    def get_next_nineoclock_time(current_time: datetime) -> datetime:
        if current_time.hour < 9:
            return NineOClockTimes._get_nineoclock_time(current_time, hour=9)
        elif current_time.hour >= 21:
            return NineOClockTimes._get_nineoclock_time(current_time, hour=9, next_day=True)
        return NineOClockTimes._get_nineoclock_time(current_time, hour=21)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_nineoclock_time(current_time, hour, next_day=False):
        new_time =  current_time.replace(
            hour=hour,
            minute=0,
            second=0,
            microsecond=0,
            tzinfo=timezone.utc,
        )

        if next_day:
            new_time += timedelta(days=1)

        return new_time
```

Comment: what if the given `current_time` was 9:49 AM in UTC+1 timezone? (8:49 AM UTC)

Comment: @hjpotter92 I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `_get_nineoclock_time` does two things, it replaces the `timezone` and it returns the next 9 O'clock time.  The function will return different values depending on whether `current_time` has a timezone or not.  That may be unexpected and seems a likely source of bugs.  I'd set the timezone somewhere else.

It is easy to calculate how many hours to add from midnight based on the current hour. Then use `timedelta` to add that many hours.

```
def get_next_nineoclock_time(current_time: datetime) -> datetime:
    hours = 9 if current_time.hour < 9 else 21 if current_time.hour < 21 else 33
    
    midnight = current_time.replace(
        hour=0,
        minute=0,
        second=0,
        microsecond=0,
    )
    
    return  midnight + timedelta(hours=hours)
```

Your could use this formula for `hours`, but I thinks it is less clear:

```
hours = 9 + 12*((current_time.hour + 3)//12)
```

Comment: Coincidentally, we realized that time zone issue today. I like this solution, thanks!

Comment: @DanielKaplan this timezone issue was what I had pointed out earlier in the comment on question :)

Comment: @hjpotter92 ah, sorry I didn't understand it

Answer (score 2):

The class has no data, and only static methods.  That suggests we don't need a class at all; plain functions should be perfectly adequate.

Comment: Since the class is used as namespace we can keep the functions in a stand alone file and just `import {file} as NineOClockTimes`. There are some drawbacks to the approach as you won't be able to subclass `NineOClockTimes`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler approach using `timedelta` to do this.

You start by getting the current hour from `now` (`now.hour`). If you subtract this from `now` it will take you to midnight. Then we add/remove an appropriate number of extra hours to get to the 9am/pm you want - in this example I add 3:

```
now = datetime.now()
print(now)
# datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 10, 23, 32, 830310)
nineish = now - timedelta(days=-1, hours=now.hour - 9) #-18 for 9pm
print(nineish)
datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 2, 9, 23, 32, 830310)
```

You can optionally also then throw away the mins/secs/usecs to get an exact date:

```
print(nineish.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0))
# datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 2, 9, 0)
```

Comment: How do I figure out the "appropriate number of hours"? Doesn't that depend on what `now` is?

Comment: The first part gets you to midnight - you then need to either add 3, or subtract 9, depending on whether you want 9pm or am. In the code I add 3 to get to the previous 9pm.

Comment: Isn't this giving me the *previous* day's 9pm? I'm asking for the next.

Comment: Apologies - misread the question. Have updated with different values to `timedelta`

Comment: This is definitely less code to think about, but I find myself thinking about how this answer works longer than I think about my existing solution. It might be a matter of extracting things into variable names or methods, etc.